# How I can convert fla to exe?

Tags: exe, fla

How I can convert .fla to .exe? I know about the built-in tools, but I'm interested in the utility.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second part of your question? If you know how to do it, then exactly what are you asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flajector, f-in-box or swfkit. 
There are also online services for the conversion

Comment: I advise f-in-box (more features)

Answer (score 5):

-Open the fla with Flash.

-Goto: File -> Publish Settings

-On the Publish Settings menu, select/tick 'Windows Projector (.exe)

-Finally, click Publish

Do you expect other than this, like using third party tools?